# neo4jclient Expression type Add is not supported

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have two Nodes - Phone and Users. 10000 Phones and 10000 users. I want connect it with relation.Its show me error **neo4jclient Expression type Add is not supported**

```
for (int k=1;k<10000;k++)
            {
                client.Cypher
                    .Match("(user1:User)", "(user2:Phone)")
                    .Where((Users user1) => user1.Fio == "Radzhab"+k)
                    .AndWhere((Phone user2) => user2.Name == "33-333"+k)
                    .Create("user1-[:HAVE_PHONE]->user2")
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
            }
```

`MATCH (user1:User), (user2:Phone) WHERE user1.Fio = "Radzhab1" AND user2.Name = "33-3331" CREATE user1-[:HAVE_PHONE]->user2;` **its work correct in console**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Neo4jClient.

As a workaround, try this:

```
for (var k = 1; k < 10000; k++)
{
    var fio = "Radzhab"+k;
    var name = "33-333"+k;
    client.Cypher
        .Match("(user1:User)", "(user2:Phone)")
        .Where((Users user1) => user1.Fio == fio)
        .AndWhere((Phone user2) => user2.Name == name)
        .Create("user1-[:HAVE_PHONE]->user2")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
}
```